# Как вывести таблицу по ширине экрана со смещением строк?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте! На рисунке 1 видно что в таблице сверху и снизу не помещается текст на экран пригодиться перемещать ползунок чтобы просмотреть все поля в таблице, подскажите как решить проблему чтобы все поля помещались под размер экрана ? 
Сверху таблица построена на тэге table, снизу на блоках div. Ожидаю увидеть результат как на Рисунке 2, ячейки таблицы смещаются и выводиться по размеру экрана.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как оно может поместиться по ширине экрана, если размеры таблицы немалые? какого именно результата вы ожидаете?

Comment: Отредактировал пост, смотрите 2 рисунок.

Comment: А есть код этого всего? Желательно бы показать.

Comment: Проект большой, что конкретно скинуть стили таблиц ?

Comment: Да. страницу, которая неверно отображается.

Comment: вот http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reMqyG, 2 таблица которая состоит из div блоков

Comment: мдя, кдассная таблица, во!